# Execution gets stuck between synchronized blocks

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this piece of code:

```
Profile a = randomProfile();
Thread workerA = new Thread(new Downloader(a));
workerA.start();        

Profile b = randomProfile();
Thread workerB = new Thread(new Downloader(b));
workerB.start();

synchronized (workerA) {
    try {
        workerA.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Error on background thread!");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

synchronized (workerB) {
    try {
        workerB.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Error on background thread!");          
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

And a `Downloader` class which implements the `Runnable` interface, and its `run()` method looks like:

```
@Override
public void run() {     
    synchronized (this) {
        //work...
        notify();
    }
}
```

Now this is working as intented, sometimes. Most of the time though, it seems to get stuck in the second synchronized block (it always gets through the first one).

Am I doing something wrong?

Also do I have some conceptual error, e.g. this implementation doesn't give me any advantage over a single thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wait()` is invoked on the `Thread` objects but the `notify()` is invoked on the `Downloader` objects.

The background threads should therefore run without a problem (although completely unsynchronized), and the main thread should always block to infinity in the first `synchronized` block because there's no-one to wake it up.

*Where this case is special is that you invoked `wait()` on the `Thread` objects themselves, which is discouraged (and by this I really mean: forbidden). When a thread terminates, it invokes `notifyAll()` on itself, so when `workerA` finishes, you get out of the first `synchronized` block. But by the time the second `synchronized` block is reached, `workerB` is already finished, so the second `wait()` will never end.*

Whether there is a conceptual error depends on what you were trying to achieve. From the code it looks very much like what you tried to do is [`join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) the background threads.

Comment: Why doesn't it always block then? Sometimes it gets through fine... Yes, I think I'll ultimately need join here, but if I call `wait()` on the `Downloader` objects, it still gets stuck

Comment: @Innkeeper It's a good question why it doesn't always block, it should and I suspect it does. Why it gets stuck even if you call the correct `wait()` is easier to explain: the background thread probably finished and already called `notify()` by the time `wait()` is encountered.

Comment: Hm, well, it is definitely working with `join()`, so I guess that's what I was looking for, thanks! If I join the two workers instead of the two `synchronized` blocks, they are being executed in parallel, so this is a valid place to use multiple threads, is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, `join()` is fine in this case but I'd probably use a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), which was designed for this exact purpose. And I definitely wouldn't use manually created `Thread`s (unless it's a training exercise), I'd use `Executor`s instead. It makes life a lot easier.

Comment: All right, I knew about the existence of higher level abstractions, I just wanted to start with the classics. Thanks!

Comment: @Innkeeper It's fine then, you should definitely learn the lower level stuff too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64747/discussion-between-biziclop-and-innkeeper).